# Architecture and patterns for developing a custom GUI designer via C# & WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, design-patterns

I only have a vague hint of spec so far, but I'm just testing the waters.  I need to create a designer that will be used for creating CBT tasks and workflows.  It must cater for custom objects (controls) as well as standard .NET WinForms controls.

I very lightly scanned some papers long ago on using the Visual Studio SDK and deployable design framework, but I can't remember anything meaningful.

1. I need some resources on building designers in general, with drag and drop, resizing, connectors, and events.
2. I need some resources on the capabilities of the Visual Studio SDK in regards to my first point.
3. I would appreciate any recommendations regarding alternative (hopefully open source) technologies and patterns.

I would lurve to write this from scratch, but I can't do that at my client's expense, so I would much prefer to leverage existing artifacts as much as possible.

**EDIT:** When I first posted, I could not recall that one tool I had in mind was the Visual Studio Shell, which allows me to create a "VS clone", with VS features, but my own branding and DSL type projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented the VS designer in one of my applications, and I'll tell you now - there is not much documentation.  Although I achieved a result I am happy with, documentation is slim.  Here are some links:

[Create And Host Custom Designers With The .NET Framework 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163634.aspx)

[System.ComponentModel.Design Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.aspx)

[DesignSurfaceManager Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.designsurfacemanager.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There's also the MSDN article called "[Extending Design-Time Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37899azc.aspx)".

The only book written on the subject seems to be "[Developing .NET Custom Controls and Designers Using C#](http://books.google.com/books/about/Developing_NET_Custom_Controls_and_Desig.html?id=f2lcvqNAeo4C)", which dates back to 2005.

I also find it odd that there's so little information on this subject.  Is writing .NET designers unpopular for some reason?  It took a while for my exploration of C# to get to the point where learning this subject made sense, and I wonder if I should make the effort.

Comment: There is relatively little need for full-blown designers these days, especially given the existence of the "DSL Tools" in the Visual Studio SDK.